# Symfony serializer ignoring arrays of objects, yet doctrine is persisting them fine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to deserialize a json payload into an Entity, I need the objects inside this array to be owned by the parent object. Example payload.

```
{
    "exportOwner": "test@example.com",
    "uniqueIdentifier": "BCD99340-70D9-4E23-91DD-C40DFB64EC9D",
    "events": [
        {
            "uniqueIdentifier": "E09FDE82-4CAA-4641-87AF-6C092D6E71C1"
        }
    ]
}
```

When sent, that particular event either exists (using the uniqueIdentifier) or it does not. If it does not, I create it. Problem is, the parent object that holds this array basically owns these, so a `OneToMany` relationship exists.

So I need to iterate over that array of events and called `setParentId()` to that of the newly created parent object. Which I assume I need to do in this block of code somewhere.

```php
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $entity = $serializer->deserialize($data, $this->type, 'json');
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($this->type);

        // If it exists update it
        if($existingEntity = $repo->findOneBy(
                array(
                "uniqueIdentifier" => $entity->getUniqueIdentifier()
                )
            )){
            $entity->setId($existingEntity->getId());
            $entityManager->merge($entity);
            $entityManager->flush();
            return $this->_200response($this->type." with uuid '".$existingEntity->getUniqueIdentifier()."' already exists. It has been updated");
        }

        // Create
        $user = $this->getUserByEmail($entity->getExportOwner());
        // $entity->setExportOwnerId($user->getId());
        // $entity->setExportOwner(null);
        $entityManager->persist($entity);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->_200response($this->type." with uuid '".$entity->getUniqueIdentifier()."' created");
```

However, doing `$entity->getEvents()` is returning an empty array.

The relationship looks like this:

```
     // Animal.php
   /**
     * @var Event[]|null
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Animal", mappedBy="animal")
     */
    private $events;


------------------------------------------------------------------

     // Event.php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Animal", inversedBy="metrics")
     */
    private $animal;
```

Even once I send the payload, and then recieved the object back, the events array is empty, yet the event exists.

This works 100% fine if I use the `@ORM\JoinTable` annotation with a `ManyToMany` relationship, but I don't really need that. I have one Animal to Many events.

Comment: Note that ->merge(); will be removed in Doctrine 3 so you might be better of without it. I think you need to get/add the events from/to the existingEntity.

Comment: Seems a bit weird that it does not know what to do with the array of events, it knows it's an Event, I would assume that because it is part of the payload it would be persisted as a related object.

Comment: Might be that the merge is messing with the result? is $entity->getEvents() also empty before you merge the entity?